# VBA Overflow for seemingly no reason

Tags: loops, excel, overflow, vba

I'm trying to write unique values from one documents k column to a different workbook's ad column.
When I dim i as string it gives an overflow error, when i Dim i as Long it gives error 1004: application defined or object defined error. Both for the line containing CarID <> Cells(i + 1, 11).
Even if i dont use loop until, but i use exit do.
That part is needed because the read column contains the same data for approx 10 instances. Not exactly, changes for every value. 
The code works properly for the first 3 values then becomes stuck and gives error. I tried changing the value to a. b. c the same problem consists.
Thanks for your help, here's the code:

```
Sub PrintCarID()

Dim ABC_App As Excel.Application
Dim carPath As String
Dim carWBook As Excel.Workbook
Dim MigrationDocument As Excel.Workbook

Dim CarID As String
Dim i As Long
Dim n As Integer
i = 0
n = 1

Set MigrationDocument = ActiveWorkbook       'activeworkbook is the document we need to print in
carPath = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 29).Value    'the path and filename for the read document
Set carWBook = Workbooks.Open(carPath)
Set ABC_App = carWBook.Parent
ABC_App.Visible = True


Do
carWBook.Activate
Do
i = i + 1
CarID = Cells(i, 11).Value


Loop Until CarID <> Cells(i + 1, 11)

MigrationDocument.Activate
Cells(n, 30).Value = CarID
n = n + 1

Loop Until CarID = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: When you have moved the final value in column 11, you set `CarID` from the first blank row. You then loop until you find a non-blank row. I would guess that string `i` is treated as an integer and overflows at 32768. With long `i`, the error comes when you attempt to access a row that does not exist. The maximum number of rows depends on your version of Excel. Try your code and tell me the value of `i` when it fails. If my theory is correct, I will post an answer with a corrected version of your code.

Comment: You could use a Dictionary - or just an advanced filter if the source data has a header row.

Comment: you were right tony the value of i is 32767 (if it is string) when it fails. i amended the code added an exit do if carID = "" to the nested loop. however the code still only prints the first three unique values even though there are about 8 of them in the document im testing the code with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you only get the first three unique values.  I cannot duplicate that problem.  Try my code and see if it fixes that problem.  If not I can only assume I have misunderstood the nature of your data.  I post images of my test data.  You will need to tell me how my data differs from yours.

The comment from Rory indicates there are more advanced techniques that may be appropriate.  Although I have made many changes to your code, I have avoided these advanced techniques.  I have given you plenty to think about.  Master all my points and the reasons for all my changes and you will be ready for the next level.

**General points**

`Workbooks.Open` opens a new workbook within the current copy of Excel.  You do not need:

```
Dim ABC_App As Excel.Application

Set ABC_App = carWBook.Parent
ABC_App.Visible = True
```

---

There are times when it is necessary and appropriate to pick up values from, or relative to, the `ActiveCell`.  Are you sure this is one of them?  Will the user remember to place the name of the source workbook in column 29 of the row where they leave the cursor?  Will they forget and leave the name of the previous workbook?  Please ask yourself if this is the most reliable method of getting the source workbook name.

You assume the source workbook will have been saved with the source worksheet open.  Are you sure this will be true?

I have used `With`statments.  This will be the correct approach 99% of the time.  Only you can know if it is the correct approach on this occasion.

---

Avoid activating worksheets.  This is a slow command particularly if you omit `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` because Excel repaints the screen every time you activate a new worksheet.

---

You get a value from column 29 of the active cell’s row and immediately use it in the `Worksbooks.Open` statement.  You do not check the value is not null and that it is the path and name of an accessible workbook.  Get into the habit of checking for as many errors as possible so you can give the user an understandable error message and a graceful exit rather than a highlighted VBA statement and an obscure error message from the VBA interpreter.

---

Avoid names like `i` and `n`.  While you are writing this macro, you will remember what `i` and `n` are.  Will you remember when you need to update this macro in six or twelve months?  I use names like `RowSrcCrnt` and `RowDestCrnt`.  I am not asking you to like my naming system, but to have a system of your own.  I can return to macros I wrote years ago and know what all the variables are.  This is a real timesaver when you need to update an old macro.

---

Avoid what I call magic numbers such as 11, 29 and 30.  Today, the data to check is in column 11 but are you sure that a new column 2 won’t be added.  Working though a macro updating it after a worksheet rearrangement can be a nightmare.  Using constants means it takes a little longer to type statements but your code is self-documenting if you use meaningful names and it saves so much time when something changes.  Often updating the constant value is all that is necessary.

**My test data and code**

My version of the worksheet within the workbook containing the macro looks like this before the macro is run:

[image: The name of the workbook to be opened]

My version of the worksheet within the workbook containing the data looks like this:

[image: The source data]

My version of the worksheet within the workbook containing the macro looks like this after the macro is run:

[image: The unquie names within the destination worksheet]

The above images match my understanding of your code.

My code is below.  I have explained every change I have made.  Some of those changes may be inappropriate for your current requirement.  My changes will be correct most of the time but only you can know if they are correct now.  Work though my code.  Come back with questions if necessary but the more you can understand the changes on your own, the faster you will develop.  Good luck.

```
Option Explicit
Sub PrintCarID()

  ' * I name my constant and variables using a sequence of keywords.
  ' * The first keyword identifies the type of information.  For example:
  '   Wsht for worksheet, Wbk for workbook, Row for row, Col for column and
  '   Rng for range.
  ' * Each subsequent keyword narrows the constant or variable down until
  '   I hsve a name that is unique within the macro or project.
  ' * If I have more than one workbook, the keyword following Wbk will identify
  '   the workbook. I know nothing about your workbooks and worksheets so have
  '   named them Source and Destination and have used keywords Src and Dest.
  ' * This is my system which you may not like.  If you do not like mine,
  '   invent your own.  Naming your constants and variables makes large macro
  '   much easier to follow particularly if you return to one after 6 or 12
  '   months.

  ' * 11 and 30 in your code are what I call magic numbers.  You say "Abracadabra!"
  '   and good (or bad) things happen but you do not know why.  Replacing 11 and 30
  '   with names makes the code easier to understand and easier to maintain.
  Const ColSrcId As Long = 11
  Const ColDestId As Long = 30

  ' * I do not like using the cell that was active when the macro was called
  '   unless this is important to how the user controls the macro. Switch
  '   back to your approach if necessary.
  Const RngWbkSrcName As String = "AC1"

  ' Chamge these values if you add header rows
  Const RowSrcDataFirst As Long = 1
  Const RowDestDataFirst As Long = 1

  ' * You use the active worksheet in the workbook containing the macro and the
  '   worksheet active when the source worksheet was saved.  This may be
  '   necessary for your macro but I have coded on the assumption it is not.
  '   Switch back to ActiveWorkbook if necessary.  Better replace "Destination"
  '   and "Source" with your names.
  Const WshtDestName As String = "Destination"
  Const WshtSrcName As String = "Source"

  Dim CarIdLast As String
  Dim Path As String
  Dim RowDestCrnt As Long
  Dim RowSrcCrnt As Long
  Dim RowSrcLast As Long
  Dim WbkDest As Workbook
  Dim WbkSrc As Workbook
  Dim WbkSrcName As String
  Dim WshtDest As Worksheet
  Dim WshtSrc As Worksheet

  ' * ThisWorkbook explicitly identifies the workbook containing the macro
  '   It is possible to execute a macro in a non-active workbook so ActiveWorkbook
  '   is not necessarily the workbook containing the macro
  Set WbkDest = ThisWorkbook        ' The workbook containing the macro

  With WbkDest

    Set WshtDest = Worksheets(WshtDestName)

    With WshtDest

      ' * carPath may be a meaningful name for you but I have used my own naming
      '   convention.  If "car" is meaningful, I would use a name like WbkCarName
      '   or WbkCarPath.
      WbkSrcName = .Range(RngWbkSrcName).Value

    End With
  End With

  If WbkSrcName = "" Then
    Call MsgBox("The name of the source workbook is missing.", vbOKOnly)
    Exit Sub
  End If

  ' * I like to place all linked workbooks and files in the same folder
  '   since this makes it easier to handle them. With your approach the
  '   user has to include the full path within the workbook name. With
  '   my approach the user only has to include specify the file name.
  Path = WbkDest.Path & "\"

  ' * Check the path and file exists.  I could check the path exists first
  '   but I doubt that would provide much extra help to the user
  If Dir$(Path & WbkSrcName) = "" Then
    Call MsgBox("I cannot find """ & Path & WbkSrcName & """.", vbOKOnly)
    Exit Sub
  End If

  ' * I have checked the file exists but the open may still fail because,
  '   for example, I may not have read permission.  There is little I can
  '   do to avoid such errors.  Te statements around the Workbook.Open
  '   switch off normal error processing so I can issue my own error
  '   message rather than have the VBA halt on the Workbook.Open statement.
  Err.Clear
  On Error Resume Next
  Set WbkSrc = Workbooks.Open(Path & WbkSrcName)
  On Error GoTo 0
  If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    Call MsgBox("My attempt to open """ & Path & WbkSrcName & """failed. " & _
                "The reason I have been given is: " & Err.Description, vbOKOnly)
    Exit Sub
  End If

  ' * You step the source row number then check it but output to the destination
  '   row then step. I  like to be consistent unless there is good reason not to
  '   be consistent.  I step afterwards for both rows.
  ' * You do not allow for header rows.  This may be correct at the moment but
  '   will it always be correct.  I allow for header rows to be added easily
  '   by making the first data row a constant
  RowDestCrnt = RowDestDataFirst

  CarIdLast = ""        ' No last Car Id

  With WbkSrc

    ' * If I was particularly careful, I would check a worksheet with name
    '   WshtSrcName exists before trying this statement.
    Set WshtSrc = Worksheets(WshtSrcName)

    With WshtSrc

      ' * This gets the last used row in column ColSrcId.  This allows me to
      '   use a For-Loop which I find clearer.
      RowSrcLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColSrcId).End(xlUp).Row

      For RowSrcCrnt = RowSrcDataFirst To RowSrcLast
        If CarIdLast <> .Cells(RowSrcCrnt, ColSrcId).Value Then
          ' * New value for CarId
          If CarIdLast <> "" Then
            ' * Have a value to copy to the destination worksheet
            WshtDest.Cells(RowDestCrnt, ColDestId).Value = CarIdLast
            RowDestCrnt = RowDestCrnt + 1
          End If
          CarIdLast = .Cells(RowSrcCrnt, ColSrcId).Value
        End If
      Next
      ' * Output final value
      If CarIdLast <> "" Then
        ' * Have a value to copy to the destination worksheet
        WshtDest.Cells(RowDestCrnt, ColDestId).Value = CarIdLast
        RowDestCrnt = RowDestCrnt + 1
      End If

    End With

    ' * Close the source workbook without saving any changes.  There should not
    '   be any changes but best to be safe.  Without SaveChanges the user will
    '   be asked if changes are to be saved.
    .Close SaveChanges:=False

  End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Tony i couldnt wish for more detailed, extensive and ready answer.
I'm reading your code, i still see some keywords im not familiar with but I'm catching up on those right now, and the code is getting clearer and clearer. 
I much like your naming convention and tips. This is a perfect answer and perfect attitude of a helper for a newbie like me. I thank you very much.

Comment: I am pleased my answer was helpful. Please accept the answer by clicking the outline tick at the top.